# Someone please elaborate the grammar rule behind this usage

Tags: grammar

'Sato looked again at the capstone, her expression one of disbelief.'

I know the sentence is perfect both grammatically and semantically because it is from a novel written by Dan Brown. However, it seems more complete to me to write:

'Sato looked again at the capstone and her expression was one of disbelief.'

Or

'Sato looked again at the capstone with her expression being one of disbelief."

What is the grammar rule behind this? Why can you just write " ..., her expression one of disbelief." ?

Comment: It's a verbless clause. If we add the verb, we have, "Sato looked again at the capstone, her expression being one of disbelief."

Comment: You are correct, it is more complete to include _was_ or _being_.  It still makes sense without either though.  You can think of that clause as equivalent to _her expression: one of disbelief_.  However, I would rethink your attitude regarding the perfection of Dan Brown's writing.  Just because Dan Brown wrote something does not mean it's correct.

Comment: BillJ is mostly right, it is a 'reduced absolute parenthetical phrase'.  Its surface structure is not a real clause because 'being' is a participle; not a real verb.  It is absolute (instead of free modifier) because it has a new subject, and it is reduced because a tense-less form of 'be' can be assumed.

Comment: >I know the sentence is perfect both grammatically and semantically because it is from a novel written by Dan Brown.  You may want to raise that bar   ;-)

Comment: To echo mcalex, don't ever assume that fiction sentences are perfectly grammatical. Even if we ignore the question of whether a specific author is a "good" or "bad" writer, fiction takes liberties with the language. "Appears in fiction" does not imply "is proper grammar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [absolute clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction). If the participle would be *being*, it is often omitted.

They are not common in speech, but reasonably common in writing.